# How to get numbers from a string?

Tags: c#

I have some strings structured like `name (1)`. Now I want to get number `1` out of it and store the number into an `int` variable.
I don't know how to use `regex`.

Is it possible to make it by using the `split` function?

Comment: Is it always going to be `name (number)`? Cause if it is, don't make regex your second problem. Just use `String.SubString` or something like that

Comment: Yeah I've tried that. However, as the length of the number varies, the `substring` function can't make it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str = "name (12345)";
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(str, "[0-9]+");
        int a = int.Parse(mc[0].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/udkNfT

Comment: Could you please explain what does the `+` sign in `"[0-9]+"` stand for?

Comment: [0-9] means a character can be number from 0 to 9, when suffixed with '+' it means 1 or more occurences of characters that are 0 to 9.

Comment: Sorry but I've encountered a small problem when applying your solution to my project. As the number in my string only appear once, I used `mc[0]` to get the number which is still of type string(I guess?). When I tried to convert it to an `int` type, I got `Argument '#1' cannot convert 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' expression to type 'string'`. How can I eventually get an int variable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you could use `Split` like this:

```
string str = "name (1)";
int result = int.Parse((str.Split(' ')[1])[1].ToString());//Output is 1
```

**EDIT:** For numbers with more than one char you can use `TakeWhile` like this:

```
string str = "name (125)";
int res = int.Parse(new string(str.Split(' ')[1].Skip(1).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));//Output is 125
```

Just don't forget to add this `using System.Linq;` to your using directive.

Comment: It seems that this solution can only deal with numbers of one character?

Comment: @PenguinGoHack...OK. Check my updated answer. It now should works for any count of char.

Comment: Well, what makes me embarrassed is that, I've accepted an answer which I thought is helpful. Now you give me a right answer, too. I'm new to Stack Overflow and I really don't know how to deal with this situation. What is the proper way?

Comment: @PenguinGoHack...It's no matter. Feel free to accept each one that you think it is more helpful. We are here to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

You can do like this:

```
var s = "name (1)";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+");
if(m.Success)
{
    int number = int.Parse(m.Value);
}
```

`\d` stand for any digit form 0 - 9. `+` is match at least one and as many as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to learn regex, you could use `String.SubString` in one line like this:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(mystr.SubString(mystr.IndexOf("(") + 1, mystr.IndexOf(")")));
```

But that is only if the String you are using is always in the format of "name (1)"

Answer (score -1):

in javascript:

```
if (/.*\((\d+)\)/.test(input)) {
  value = parseInt(RegExp.$1, 10);
}
```

in other languages you can do something similar. javascript was easiest to get a console up for and you didn't specify.

the .* means anything...
the ( means a literal (
the \d means a digit, the surrounding (\d+) means group 1 or more digits
then a closing ) is the literal )

Answer (score -1):

Edited post for OP title change, you could do something like this for C#

```
 int numVal = Int32.Parse("-105");
Console.WriteLine(numVal);
```

this will print out -105

Comment: Sorry it's my fault. I've edited the question and now it's more clear.